# How to send .proto files from android device over USB connection

Tags: android, usb, protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm involved in a project where there is communication between an android device and a vending machine over USB. We need to send .proto files, but I don't know how this is generally done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the two devices has to be *USB host*  on the other has to be implemented any USB device class, easiest is *USB mass storage* also possible is *USB ACM* and others.

In addition you need access/permissions to the folders from which you copy and to which you copy. This can be a problem if the Android is not *rooted*. Then the easiest way is to **mount** the filesystem of one of the machines on the other and copy the file using linux commands (BusyBox,...) or *adb*

with `lsusb` the device classes that are implemented on a device can be listed, see http://www.linuxnix.com/find-usb-device-details-in-linuxunix-using-lsusb-command/